# Real Analysis - Sequence of Positive Numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Can somebody tell me if I'm on the right track. What is the next step?
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kq3n.png)

[image]

Comment: What is your attempt?

Answer (score 1):

You have the main idea, but you need to present it rigorously. Given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $k> N$ we have $a_k<\epsilon.$ This is because $a_k\to 0.$ Furthermore we know that for all $k$ there exists $N'$ such that for all $n>N'$ we have 
$$|b-b_n|<a_k.$$
Now if we choose $k=N+1>N$ then we have $a_k<\epsilon.$ Furthermore for this choice of $k$ there exists $N'$ such that for all $n>N'$ we have 
$$|b-b_n|<a_k<\epsilon.$$
Thus given $\epsilon>0$ we have found an $N'$ such that for all $n>N'$ we have 
$$|b-b_n|<\epsilon$$
as desired.